# Series.Formula changes characters e.g. commas to semicolons

Tags: excel, vba, charts

I wrote code to go through the data (as shown below) and collect data based on category. Such data will be added to dedicated data series and plotted at the ScatterPlot.
[image]

`Series.Formula` changes some characters e.g. commas, semicolons (pictures below) and an error pops up.

How it looks before:
[image]

How it looks after:
[image]

```
Dim mySeries As Series    
For Each mySeries In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Test").Chart.SeriesCollection
    For Each c In Source.Range("U7:U13")
               
        If c = mySeries.Name Then
                    
            k = 0
            Do While Cells(c.row, c.Column) = Cells(c.row + k, c.Column)
                k = k + 1
            Loop
            k = k - 1
                
            srsX = "{"
            srsY = "{"
            For j = c.row To c.row + k
                srsX = srsX & (Cells(j, c.Column + 2)) & "\" '& Application.International(xlListSeparator)
                srsY = srsY & (Cells(j, c.Column + 1)) & "\" '& Application.International(xlListSeparator)
                        
            Next j
            srsX = Left(srsX, Len(srsX) - 1) & "}"
            srsY = Left(srsY, Len(srsY) - 1) & "}"
                    
            With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Test").Chart.SeriesCollection
                trashme = "=SERIES(""" & mySeries.Name & """" & Application.International(xlListSeparator) & srsX & Application.International(xlListSeparator) & srsY & Application.International(xlListSeparator) & mySeries.PlotColorIndex & ")"
                MsgBox trashme
                mySeries.Formula = "=SERIES(""" & mySeries.Name & """" & Application.International(xlListSeparator) & srsX & Application.International(xlListSeparator) & srsY & Application.International(xlListSeparator) & mySeries.PlotColorIndex & ")"
            End With
        End If    
                
    Next c
Next mySeries
```

Comment: VBA is En-US centric so I think you need the `,` as the separator if you are using `Series.Formula`. There is `Series.FormulaLocal` as well... haven't tested.

Comment: `Series.FormulaLocal`  solves a problem. Thanks

Comment: Is it possible to delete `Series.FormulaLocal` not the entire `Series`?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want to do.